# How to fix my input validation in my c version of Tic Tac Toe?

Tags: c++, validation, input, cin

I am creating a game of Tic Tac Toe in C using a console based interface. Two players go against each other by choosing a number from 1-9 to place their pieces on the board (For example if you type in one, then it would place your piece on the top left corner, typing in two will place it in the top middle, typing in three would place it in the right top corner and so on). However my main problem with my code is that whenever someone types in a letter the game would basically be stuck in a eternal loop until you close the program, I tried many solutions (Such as using a switch case, making a input a char, etc.) but I don't know how to fix it. Thank you.

```
//Libaries
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>

using namespace std;
//Indentifers
void gamescreen(); //Used to display the board
char gamecondition(); //This is indentifer is used to check the game is won lost/draw
void playerturn();
void playernames();
int resultsscreen();
int turn;
int playerinput(int playerchoice);
int Player1Score, Player2Score;

//Variables
//int menuchoice; //Not Neeeded for now
char PlayerPiece = 'X';
char GameWinner;
char board[3][3] = { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' }; //Creates a 3 by 3 matrix, which is basically the board.
int playerchoice; //Reason why playerchoice is a int rather than a char is because
string Player1Name, Player2Name;
char finalchoice;

void playernames()
{
    cout << "Player 1 please enter your name" << endl; //Asks for the first username
    cin >> Player1Name; // Gets the first user name
    cout << "Player 2 please enter your name" << endl; //Asks for the second username
    cin >> Player2Name; // Gets the second user name
    cout << "Player 1 Name is: " << Player1Name << " " << "and Player 2 name is: " << Player2Name << endl; //Displays Usernames
}

void gamescreen() //Displays the board on the screen to the players
{
    system("cls"); //CLears the screen again, to make the game clean and tidy
    cout << "SCOREBOARD: " << Player1Name << ": " << Player1Score << " " << Player2Name << ": " << Player2Score << endl;
    cout << "\n" << endl;

    cout << board[0][0] << " | " << board[0][1] << " | " << board[0][2] << endl;
    cout << board[1][0] << " | " << board[1][1] << " | " << board[1][2] << endl;
    cout << board[2][0] << " | " << board[2][1] << " | " << board[2][2] << endl;
}

void playercheck()
{
    cout << "It is Player: " << PlayerPiece << " Turn, please put select a piece on the board" << endl;
    cin >> playerchoice;
    playerinput(playerchoice);
}
int playerinput(int playerchoice)
{
    if (playerchoice > 9 || playerchoice < 1 || cin.fail())
    {
        cout << "Please enter a number from 1-9!" << endl;
        cin.clear();
        playercheck();
    }
    else
    {
        if (playerchoice == 1) //If the player chose this one then
        {
            if (board[0][0] == '1') //This turns the number into a position on the board, it checks if the place is valid and there isn't a position on the board. If so then it places the player piece down
                board[0][0] = PlayerPiece; //If the condition is true, then it replaces that board space with the player piece
            else
            {
                cout << "This move is invalid because this space has been claimed" << endl; //However if there was not a space or the player just decides to put a number other than 1-9 then this message pops up
                playercheck(); //This function is called again to elimate the need for loops.
            }
        }
        else if (playerchoice == 2) //If the player chose this one then
        {
            if (board[0][1] == '2') //This turns the number into a position on the board, it checks if the place is valid and there isn't a position on the board. If so then it places the player piece down
                board[0][1] = PlayerPiece;
            else
            {
                cout << "This move is invalid because this space has been claimed" << endl; //However if there was not a space or the player just decides to put a number other than 1-9 then this message pops up
                playercheck(); //This function is called again to elimate the need for loops.
            }
        }
        else if (playerchoice == 3) //If the player chose this one then
        {
            if (board[0][2] == '3') //This turns the number into a position on the board, it checks if the place is valid and there isn't a position on the board. If so then it places the player piece down
                board[0][2] = PlayerPiece;
            else
            {
                cout << "This move is invalid because this space has been claimed" << endl; //However if there was not a space or the player just decides to put a number other than 1-9 then this message pops up
                playercheck(); //This function is called again to elimate the need for loops.
            }
        }
        else if (playerchoice == 4) //If the player chose this one then
        {
            if (board[1][0] == '4') //This turns the number into a position on the board, it checks if the place is valid and there isn't a position on the board. If so then it places the player piece down
                board[1][0] = PlayerPiece;
            else
            {
                cout << "This move is invalid because this space has been claimed" << endl; //However if there was not a space or the player just decides to put a number other than 1-9 then this message pops up
                playercheck(); //This function is called again to elimate the need for loops.
            }
        }
        else if (playerchoice == 5) //If the player chose this one then
        {
            if (board[1][1] == '5') //This turns the number into a position on the board, it checks if the place is valid and there isn't a position on the board. If so then it places the player piece down
                board[1][1] = PlayerPiece;
            else
            {
                cout << "This move is invalid because this space has been claimed" << endl; //However if there was not a space or the player just decides to put a number other than 1-9 then this message pops up
                playercheck(); //This function is called again to elimate the need for loops.
            }
        }
        else if (playerchoice == 6) //If the player chose this one then
        {
            if (board[1][2] == '6') //This turns the number into a position on the board, it checks if the place is valid and there isn't a position on the board. If so then it places the player piece down
                board[1][2] = PlayerPiece;
            else
            {
                cout << "This move is invalid because this space has been claimed" << endl; //However if there was not a space or the player just decides to put a number other than 1-9 then this message pops up
                playercheck(); //This function is called again to elimate the need for loops.
            }
        }
        else if (playerchoice == 7) //If the player chose this one then
        {
            if (board[2][0] == '7') //This turns the number into a position on the board, it checks if the place is valid and there isn't a position on the board. If so then it places the player piece down
                board[2][0] = PlayerPiece;
            else
            {
                cout << "This move is invalid because this space has been claimed" << endl; //However if there was not a space or the player just decides to put a number other than 1-9 then this message pops up
                playercheck(); //This function is called again to elimate the need for loops.
            }
        }
        else if (playerchoice == 8) //If the player chose this one then
        {
            if (board[2][1] == '8') //This turns the number into a position on the board, it checks if the place is valid and there isn't a position on the board. If so then it places the player piece down
                board[2][1] = PlayerPiece;
            else
            {
                cout << "This move is invalid because this space has been claimed" << endl; //However if there was not a space or the player just decides to put a number other than 1-9 then this message pops up
                playercheck(); //This function is called again to elimate the need for loops.
            }
        }
        else if (playerchoice == 9) //If the player chose this one then
        {
            if (board[2][2] == '9') //This turns the number into a position on the board, it checks if the place is valid and there isn't a position on the board. If so then it places the player piece down
                board[2][2] = PlayerPiece;
            else
            {
                cout << "This move is invalid because this space has been claimed" << endl; //However if there was not a space or the player just decides to put a number other than 1-9 then this message pops up
                playercheck(); //This function is called again to elimate the need for loops.
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Please enter in a valid number!" << endl;
            playercheck();
            //Fail safe just in case the first one failed somehow.
        }
    }
    //The if statements about choices, etc. Checking if this space has not been picked yet

    //NEED TO CHANGE ALL OF THE NUMBERS
    return 1;
}

void playerturn()
{
    if (PlayerPiece == 'X')
        PlayerPiece = 'O';
    else
        PlayerPiece = 'X';
}

char gamecondition() //This is used to check the win conidtion aka who won or if not how does this game draw?
{
    //Checks for the first player
    if (board[0][0] == 'X' && board[0][1] == 'X' && board[0][2] == 'X')
        return 'X'; //Basically this checks if the there is three in a row in the board, if show it returns the value X, which will be shown in the main. (Basically if GameWinner == X, cout << "Player1 wins!" << endl;
    if (board[1][0] == 'X' && board[1][1] == 'X' && board[1][2] == 'X')
        return 'X';
    if (board[2][0] == 'X' && board[2][1] == 'X' && board[2][2] == 'X')
        return 'X';
    if (board[0][0] == 'X' && board[1][0] == 'X' && board[2][0] == 'X')
        return 'X';
    if (board[0][1] == 'X' && board[1][1] == 'X' && board[2][1] == 'X')
        return 'X';
    if (board[0][2] == 'X' && board[1][2] == 'X' && board[2][2] == 'X')
        return 'X';
    if (board[0][0] == 'X' && board[1][1] == 'X' && board[2][2] == 'X')
        return 'X';
    if (board[2][0] == 'X' && board[1][1] == 'X' && board[0][2] == 'X')
        return 'X'; //Returns X to the gamecondition()

                    //Checks for the second player
    if (board[0][0] == 'O' && board[0][1] == 'O' && board[0][2] == 'O')
        return 'O'; //Basically this checks if the there is three in a row in the board, if show it returns the value X, which will be shown in the main. (Basically if gameconidition == X, cout << "Player1 wins!" << endl;
    if (board[1][0] == 'O' && board[1][1] == 'O' && board[1][2] == 'O')
        return 'O';
    if (board[2][0] == 'O' && board[2][1] == 'O' && board[2][2] == 'O')
        return 'O';
    if (board[0][0] == 'O' && board[1][0] == 'O' && board[2][0] == 'O')
        return 'O';
    if (board[0][1] == 'O' && board[1][1] == 'O' && board[2][1] == 'O')
        return 'O';
    if (board[0][2] == 'O' && board[1][2] == 'O' && board[2][2] == 'O')
        return 'O';
    if (board[0][0] == 'O' && board[1][1] == 'O' && board[2][2] == 'O')
        return 'O';
    if (board[2][0] == 'O' && board[1][1] == 'O' && board[0][2] == 'O')
        return 'O';

    else
        return '/'; //If it isn't either O or X then returns '/' which shows it's a draw
}



int main()
{
    playernames();
    turn = 0; //This is a turn counter, this will be used to determine the draw (Without it the game will keep on going)
    gamescreen(); //Displays the game screen again
    while (1)
    {
        turn++; //If the game hasn't been completed yet then adds 1 to the number counter
        playercheck();
        gamescreen();
        if (gamecondition() == 'X')
        {
            cout << Player1Name << "X wins!" << endl;
            Player1Score++;
            resultsscreen();
        }
        else if (gamecondition() == 'O')
        {
            cout << Player2Name << " wins!" << endl;
            Player2Score++;
            resultsscreen();
        }
        else if (gamecondition() == '/' && turn == 9)
        {
            cout << "It's a draw!" << endl;
            resultsscreen();
        }
        playerturn();
    }
}
int resultsscreen()
{
    cout << "The current score is:" << endl;
    cout << Player1Name << ":" << Player1Score << endl;
    cout << Player2Name << ":" << Player2Score << endl;
    cout << "Would you like to play again, Y/N?" << endl;

    cin >> finalchoice;

    if (finalchoice == 'Y' || finalchoice == 'y')
    {
        turn = 0;
        board[0][0] = '1', board[0][1] = '2', board[0][2] = '3';
        board[1][0] = '4', board[1][1] = '5', board[1][2] = '6';
        board[2][0] = '7', board[2][1] = '8', board[2][2] = '9';
        system("cls");
        gamescreen();
        playercheck();
        playerturn();
        playerinput(playerchoice);
    }
    if (finalchoice == 'N' || finalchoice == 'n')
    {
        if (Player1Score > Player2Score)
        {
            cout << Player1Name << " wins!" << endl;
            system("pause");
            exit(0);
        }
        if (Player1Score < Player2Score)
        {
            cout << Player2Name << " wins!" << endl;
            system("pause");
            exit(0);
        }
        else if (Player1Score == Player2Score)
        {
            cout << "It's a draw!" << endl;
            system("pause");
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9855649/check-if-input-is-a-number-and-if-not-return-to-input

Comment: Globals all the way down!

Comment: Put all your global variables in a struct and pass it by reference, it will be much cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a user enters wrong input, you'll need to do two things:

1. Clear the state of the input stream, which you have in your program.
2. Ignore the rest of the line, which you don't have.

What you need is:

```
if (playerchoice > 9 || playerchoice < 1 || cin.fail())
{
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    cout << "Please enter a number from 1-9!" << endl;
    playercheck();
}
```

Make sure to add

```
#include <limits>
```

to be able to use `std::numeric_limits`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method you can apply to `cin` called `fail()` that:

- returns `true` if the input to a variable is of the same type as that variable
- returns `false` if the input to a variable is not of the same type as that variable

So in your `playercheck()` function, where you're taking the input and `playerchoice` is defined as type `int`,

```
void playercheck()
{
    cout << "It is Player: " << PlayerPiece << " Turn, please put select a piece on the board" << endl;
    cin >> playerchoice;
    playerinput(playerchoice);
}
```

add a while loop in the above that **repeatedly checks** for an integer and numbers 1-9 until you get the appropriate response.

```
void playercheck()
{
    cout << "It is Player: " << PlayerPiece << " Turn, please put select a piece on the board" << endl;
    cin >> playerchoice;

    //while the input it less than 1, more than 9, or NOT an integer
    while (playerchoice < 1 || playerchoice > 9 || cin.fail()) 
    {
       cout << "You did not enter an appropriate response." << endl;
       cout << "Please, enter in a digit between 1 and 9." << endl;



       //clear the input flag on the stream so we can recheck cin.fail()
       cin.clear();
       //skip up to 256 characters in the pursuit of skipping to the next newline
       cin.ignore(256, '\n');

       cin >> playerchoice;
    }

    playerinput(playerchoice);
}
```